# Jest cannot find tests when tests are located under `node_modules` directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

After I performed refactoring on my project, I found that Jest could not find any test modules. It reported following error.

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
No files found in /home/.../node_modules/.../... /api.
Make sure Jest's configuration does not exclude this directory.
To set up Jest, make sure a package.json file exists.
Jest Documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
Pattern:  - 0 matches
```

After I examined a while, I found the smallest reproducible example is following :

**node_modules/foo.js**

```js
function foo() { 
  return 'hello'; 
} 
module.exports.foo = foo;
```

**node_modules/foo.test.js**

```js
test( 'foo' , ()=>{ 
  console.error( require('./foo.js' ).foo() ); 
});
```

And if `foo.js` and `foo.test.js` are moved out from `node_modules` directory, Jest works as normal.

---

In order to avoid long relative package names, I put all files under `node_modules` directory. If possible, I don't want to relocate them.

Is there any workaround or, if possible, any permanent proper solution for the issue?

---

Edited)
Why do you want to put those in `node_modules` ? 
See [Document src/node_modules as official solution for absolute imports](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1065)

Comment: Why are you putting tests in `node_modules`? That's where external libraries go, not your source files or tests. A normal project structure would have `src` and `test` folders in the base directory.

Comment: @ggorlen  It is for avoiding long relative package name ... I think this post explains the problem very well... 

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1065

Comment: Thanks, but that thread is from 2016. I haven't seen this pattern in recent years and there are [good reasons not to do it](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/741#issuecomment-249391170).

Comment: @ggorlen How do people do about the long package name? I am in Japan and I am severely alone to work with Node.js thing ... I really want to know better way to counter the problem.

Comment: @ggorlen  I'm glad you read it :)  Actually long long time ago ... sometime around 2012 or something that, I have read that Isaac Schlueter mentioned like "... put everything in node_modules and the problem was solved" ...  I have been searching for the article but I still haven't found it. 

I did think it was a bad idea; I still do.

Comment: I have the same issue this is the path I am working with `/home/thomas/Code/node_modules/react/react-error-boundary`

Answer (score -1):

### This is a known bug and the bug was already fixed.

A quick fix is creating `jest.config.js` in the root directory of your project tree as following :

```js
const config = { 
  "testEnvironment": "node", 
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [], 
  "haste": { 
    "retainAllFiles": true 
  } 
}; 
module.exports = config;
```

Or you can add following in the `package.json` :

```
"jest": { 
    "testEnvironment": "node", 
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [], 
    "haste" : { 
      "retainAllFiles": true 
    } 
}
```

This answer is a sort of my reminder; hoping this saves a couple of precious hours of my friends.

- [Jest not running tests in src/node_modules #2145 (Jest)](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2145)
- [Enable src/node_modules #1081 (Create React App)](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/1081)
- [Bug: Unable to run a test from whitelisted "node_modules" #11781](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11781)
- [fix: Allow searching for tests in node_modules #11084 (Jest)](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/11084/)